# Overlay an image over video using OpenGL ES shaders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I am trying to understand the basic concepts of OpenGL. A week into it, I am still far from there. Once I am in glsl, I know what to do but I find getting there is the tricky bit.

I am currently able to pass in video pixels which I manipulate and present. I have then been trying to add a still image as an overlay. This is where I get lost. My end goal is to end up in the same fragment shader with pixel data from both my video and my still image. I imagine this means I need two textures and pass on two pixel buffers. I am currently passing the video pixels like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &textures[0]);

//target, texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

Would I then repeat this process on textures[1] with the second buffer from the image? If so, do I then bind both GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1? ...and would my shader look something like this?

```
uniform sampler2D videoData;
uniform sampler2D imageData;
```

once I am in the shader? It seems no matter what combination I try, image and video always ends up being just video data in both these.

Sorry for the many questions merged in here, just want to clear my many assumptions and move on. To clarify the question a bit, what do I need to do to add pixels from a still image in the process described? ("easy to understand" sample code or any types of hints would be appreciated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not even bothering to write this code yourself? I have all of this within my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework, and setting up a video camera source, pulling in an image, and overlaying that image on the video can be done using code like the following:

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
filter = [[GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WID-small.jpg"];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[sourcePicture processImage];            
[sourcePicture addTarget:filter];
[filter addTarget:filterView];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

This all uses OpenGL ES 2.0 behind the scenes to apply fragment shaders to the video frames and still images, and it does so faster than anything else I'm aware of on iOS. For devices that support it, I've tuned this to use some additional optimizations to speed the image and video frame upload process.

To answer your specific questions here, yes, you'd create two texture uniforms like you show there. You'd need to get the identifiers for each back from your linked shader program before using them. In your code, you'd need to bind your two textures to two different texture units, and then assign the values of those texture units to your uniforms using code similar to the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sourceTexture);
glUniform1i(filterInputTextureUniform, 2);  

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterSourceTexture2);                
glUniform1i(filterInputTextureUniform2, 3);
```

A common mistake that I've seen people make is to use a texture name in the `glUniform1i()` here, instead of the texture unit that texture is bound to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Brad. ...and also thanks for all the effort you've put in to share your experiences. I've read many of your other answers here on SO and also picked up a lot from your previous examples. I am aware of your open source framework (hard to miss when doing opengl on the iPhone), perhaps I'll use it in the future but for now I am just looking at learning it. I'll accept this an answer and will continue tomorrow.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo - I've tried to make that framework a reference in itself, so I've incorporated the things I've learned within it. If you're trying to puzzle this out, it's not a bad place to go for some sample code. Based on what you described, it really does sound like you had one uniform set up right, but were binding a single texture unit to both uniforms instead of each one individually.

Comment: Yep, I just got it working. My issues was in the glUniform1() call.

Comment: I try to to this over and over again (as my image changes), but after some iterations I do get ```Assertion failure in -[GPUImageFramebuffer unlock]``` in ```GPUImageFrameBuffer``` at line 269 ```    NSAssert(framebufferReferenceCount > 0, @"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?");``` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @swalkner - That's a completely new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need multitexturing using glActiveTextureARB
Have a look at this tutorial http://www.clockworkcoders.com/oglsl/tutorial8.htm

Comment: That won't apply to OpenGL ES 2.0, which they're using here. That tutorial is for desktop OpenGL and much of it won't work for this.